# Android studio is not adding .so files to .apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, apk, aar

I'm creating an SDK/library which results in .aar file that contains **five .so files**. This .aar file is uploaded and hosted on maven repository and should be used by some applications. The problem occurs when I am trying to use .aar file hosted on this maven repo, in lets call it **sample application**. There are three possible results:

1. Android studio is adding all five .so files to .apk and everything runs ok (very rare situation).
2. Android studio is adding only one .so file to .apk and I'm getting crashes because native libraries can't be loaded.
3. Android studio is missing all five .so files and as above, I'm getting crashes because native libraries can't be loaded

The problem here is that this is totally random situation. I've checked .aar file after it is generated by Android Studio (everything is packed inside as it should be), after uploading it to maven repository (all .so files are still there), weight of the .aar is always the same.

I have tried a lot of things and I'm out of options why this may by happening while building sample application .apk file.

Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: It would be helpful to add some example code or even the sources of such a sample application and the .aar file or so.